# Git-LFS History Download

Tags: github, git-lfs

I've recently been using a new repository with LFS enabled and full of binary files (like PCB schematics and project files). When I download old commits through GitHub's interface as compressed ZIP's, the binary files are empty, whereas the ascii files are fine.

The same thing happens when you download a zip of the repo of the current version. (Git clone works as expected).

I've used this same process at another company and was able to download old commits just fine, is there something else that needs to be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible to control whether archives get LFS objects embedded in them.  You can control this option in the repository settings under Archives.

Note that this option is not available on GitHub Enterprise Server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue with GitHub.](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/903)
You have to use `git clone` to get the LFS data, unfortunately. If you need to have the entire LFS history as well, use `git lfs fetch --all` after cloning.